# trying to install Ubuntu but i886 CPU detected and won't install

Tags: boot, kernel

I am trying to install Ubuntu Linux from a USB to an old Dell Dimension PC using Windows XP and a Celeron D. Sorry I don't have the Dell model number. I get the error message: "kernel requires X86-64 CPU, but only detected i886 CPU - unable to boot please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU"

I entered the BIOS and tried to enable Intel visualization technology or AMD or Intel VT-x - whatever might look like it, but there is no option like this.

How can I fix this or get around this to install Linux?

I don't care if I lose the Windows XP OS, that's the point anyway.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.
Pete

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you download an **iso file with an i386 kernel** (alias 32-bit version). For such an old computer it is necessary to use an i386 kernel. It is also a big advantage to select a community flavour of Ubuntu with a light desktop environment, lighter than standard Ubuntu,

- **Lubuntu** with the ultra-light desktop environment LXDE
- **Ubuntu MATE** with the medium-light desktop environment MATE
- **Xubuntu** with the medium-light desktop environment XFCE

See these links,

[releases.ubuntu.com/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

[How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)